# Understanding Proof that $\mathbb{R} \setminus A$ is dense. Verify proof.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

Here's the proof I was given but with two minor? differences

Proposition.- If $A$ is countable then $\mathbb{R} \setminus A $ is dense.

Proof:
Suppose otherwise, then there exists real numbers $a$ and $b$, with $a < b$, such that there is no $a < x < b$ with $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus A $. To put it in another way, if $a < x < b$ then $x \notin \mathbb{R} \setminus A$. As $ \mathbb{R} \setminus A$ is the complement of $A$, we see that if $a < x < b$ then $x \in A$. Thus,$(x,y) \subseteq A$. But $A$ is countable and $(x,y)$ is not, this leads to a contradiction. QED.

### -----

Is it correct to assume that $(x,y)$ should be $(a,b)$? I'm thinking it doesn't invalidate the proof.

Why is it better to have $(a,b)$ (or $(x,y)$)?

Outside of the fact that all open intervals are uncountable and therefore cannot be a subset of a countable set, why it would follow that $(x,y)$ (or $(a,b)$) is contained in A in the proof?

I can see why $x$ is in $A$ but it was given to me with two options for the next line. I'm not sure the change in versions affects the reasoning behind (1) why the interval (-,-) is contained in A, and (2) if there's more to said interval contradicting the countability of A (outside of the fact that open intervals can't be a subset of countable sets)?

Thanks

Comment: I believe it should read $ (a,b) \subseteq A$ since both a and b appear in A in the previous line. Since I'm new to this, any corrections or affirmations would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The proof is not correct. What that means with $y$? You don't even need it. That's enough to take the interval $(a,b)$, this interval is contained in $A$ and is uncountable, because every nongenerate interval of the real line is uncountable, which contradicts...

Comment: I am not sure where the (x,y) came from. The second time I saw anything on this proof it used the real numbers $a < b$ to make the interval $(a,b)$. I think you have confirmed that the ending of the proof should be : ..."we see that if $a < x < b$ then $x \in A$. Thus,$(a,b) \subseteq A$. But $A$ is countable and $(a,b)$ is not, this leads to a contradiction. QED." I'm leaving this open to see if anyone else can give insight. Thanks

Comment: Yes that's true....

Answer (score 0):

The proof has a few errors.  In the second sentence of the proof "$x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus A$" should be "$x \not\in \mathbb{R}\setminus A$" (By the way, the second sentence should be split in two. The second comma should be a period.) You are correct to say that "$(x,y)$" should be "$(a,b)$" in the third sentence, since the second sentence says that every number between $a$ and $b$ is in $A$. Also, "$(x,y)$" should be "$(a,b)$" in the final sentence.

Comment: I'm supposed to understand why "the open interval $(a, b)$ is contained in A  and  since $(a, b) \subseteq $  A, this contradicts the fact that A is countable." My answer is that $(a, b)$ is in A because a is the complement of $\mathbb{R} \setminus A$ and it contradicts A because any open interval is uncountable, and an uncountable set cannot be a subset to a countable set. Are there other  reasons why the open interval $(a, b)$ is contained in A  and  since $(a, b) \subseteq $  A, this contradicts the fact that A is countable." ? Please note this is for an upcoming exam, I'm only studying now

Comment: Other reasons?  Are you asking if additional steps need to be put in the proof ?(I do not think so, but you might, for example, need to know the proof that $(a,b)$ is uncountable for your exam.) Or are you looking for alternative proofs? (None come to my mind at the moment.)